# How can I stop gnatmake inlining functions?

Tags: debugging, inline, gnu-make, ada, gnat

I'm trying to debug an `Ada` program with `gdb`. Specifically, I'm trying to put a breakpoint in a function like the following:

```
function Moment(OC: Object'Class) return Float is
begin
    return OC.X_Coord * OC.Area;
end Moment;
```

I can put the breakpoint, and the execution stops when it is reached. My problem is that, when I use the gdb's source code  view (with `wh`) I can't see the source code.

I suspected that it's caused by `gnatmake`, that is inlining the described function even if I apply the options `-O0 -g`. For checking this, I have tried to add a `Put_Line` call to stop gnatmake inlining my function, and it has worked: with the following function I can stop the execution and see the source code:

```
function Moment(OC: Object'Class) return Float is
begin
    Put_Line("ASDASD");
    return OC.X_Coord * OC.Area;
end Moment;
```

**How can I stop `gnatmake` inlining functions?**

Comment: Are you sure the function is actually inlined? This site seems to indicate it would not be: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Inlining-of-Subprograms.html I suspect perhaps gdb is assuming the function is an expression function? A minimal working example would be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There is the switch `-fno-inline` to prevent inlining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-cargs -fno-inline` to your gnatmake or gprbuild command line, or `-fno-inline` to your project file.